# JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit - drag and drop html content onto nodes. Rearrange nodes by dragging and dropping

Tags: javascript, infovis

I was curious if anybody knows how to drag and drop html content onto a node in InfoViz Toolkit. I need to be able to detect when user attempts to drag an item that is outside of the graph and drops it onto one of the nodes.

Also I am curious if anybody knows how to move a node to a new parent by dragging and dropping